# Como obtener un objeto posicion get(i) de un ArrayList enviado por Intent de otro activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-intent

Hola soy un poco novato y tengo pequeños errores aun, tengo dificultades al intentar interactuar con una lista desde otro activity, ya la pase por Intent viendo respuestas anteriores como esta e implementé `Serializable`:

```
//en el activity1
ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SegundaActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("lista", lista);
startActivity(intent);

//en el "activiti2"
ArrayList<String> lista = (ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("lista");
```

pero al momento de querer sacar un objeto asi ejemplo:

```
for (int i=0; i < lista.size(); i++){
            if (lista.get(i).getTitulo.equals(""))...etc
        }
```

no puedo y solo puedo escribir:

```
for (int i=0; i < lista.size(); i++){
        if (lista.get(i).getBytes())
    }
```

Comment: Estás enviando un ArrayList de String, ¿no tendrías que estar enviando un ArrayList de objetos cuya clase implementa Serializable ? Dicha clase tendría definidos los métodos getTitulo() y getBytes().

Answer (score 0):

Es correcto la forma de recibir el ArrayList en tu Activity destino:

```
ArrayList<String> lista = (ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("lista");
```

ahora **para obtener los valores se realiza mediante el método `get(...)` definiendo el indice del elemento.**

---

Suponiendo que tienes 3 elementos en tu `ArrayList`, puedes obtener sus valores de esta manera:

```
  System.out.println("Titulo : " + lista.get(0));
  System.out.println("Nombre : " + lista.get(1));
  System.out.println("Descripcion : " + lista.get(2));
```

o puedes realizar un bucle para obtener todos los elementos contenidos en la lista de esta forma:

```
ArrayList<String> lista = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("lista");
    for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++){
        System.out.println("Elemento en indice " + i + " valor: " + lista.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien a que te refieres con "valores" como tag, la lista en mi caso tiene 3 variables con valor String que es Titulo Nombre Descripcion. necesito sacar el valor de cualquiera de esos.

Comment: Ok entonces el primer valor serìa Titulo (lista.get(0)) el segundo Nombre (lista.get(1)) y el tercero Descripcion (lista.get(2)), te sugiero uses el còdigo del bucle para que obtengas los valores

Comment: creo no me di a entender muy bien, o no entiendo yo bien la respuesta, el mismo array posee una lista de Titulos (que puede tener cosas como Cocina Comedor Baño) Nombre (que tendria cosas como Juan Pedro Paco Hernesto) Descripcion (que tendria cosas como Alto Bajo Nuevo Flaco)